# Setting splitActionBarWhenNarrow from Java on Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm wondering if it would be possible to tell android to split the ActionBar only when I want it to, but on the same Activity. My use case is that by default, the actions I have on the bar are OK to be collapsed, but on a long click on an item, I enter an "Edit Task" mode, where the action bar is used to provide some shorthands to edit a task. I'd like this "edit mode" to use the split action bar, as it has icon's that are better off to be visible right away, and keep the "not split" action bar for the general view - where it's just "settings" etc.

So the question is, can I set `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` from the code, instead of hardcode it in the Manifest?

PS: I'm using ActionBar Sherlock.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The native action bar can be set into split mode by calling `getWindow().setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW)`.

Window UI options cannot be read after they are set so with ActionBarSherlock you have to call `getSherlock().setUiOptions(...)`. You don't have to call both. ABS will automatically call the above when appropriate.

This *must* be done before the decor view has been created. The safest place to put this call to ensure that always happens is in your activity `onCreate` method **before** you call `super.onCreate`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question!

Sadly it's seemingly impossible to swap the split / no-split modes on an existing activity. I guess I'll create a details activity that will have the split action bar then, makes sense anyway I think :-)

Comment: What is getSherlock() function?

Comment: @tasomaniac It is part of ActionBarSherlock which the OP refers to in his question.

Comment: I have getSherlockActivity() but not getSherlock() function. I am confused.

Comment: I'm using ActionBar Sherlock with min API 8. ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW is only available in 14.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the ActionBarSherlockSamples, SplitActionModes.java. In this example, when the button 'Start' is pressed, a split action bar shows up in the bottom of the screen:

Call this to show the split actionbar:

```
mMode = startActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());
```

mMode is type of ActionMode and you need to call 'finish()' on it when you want the action bar to go away.

AnActionModeOfEpicPropotions is an implementation of ActionMode.Callback:

```
private final class AnActionModeOfEpicProportions implements ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // add your menu here...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // handles your action menu clicked event
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying if I could have an ActionBar in one Activity and a Split one in another.

I added the action bar in onCreateOptionsMenu in both the activities and added 
    getWindow().setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);

right before onCreate in the activity I wanted the split action and to my surprise it worked. :)

Then I used getActionBar().hide() to hide the split action bar on button click and it worked too.

I guess if you could try this, you can get this working and customized to your need. Hiding it initially and onLongClick showing it up and after the necessary actions are performed hiding it again.
(The only thing I missed is checking this with support libraries. Will do and update you)

Hope, this might help you in some way. Happy coding :)

Answer (score -2):

```
private final class AnActionModeOfEpicProportions implements ActionMode.Callback
{
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode,Menu menu)
  {
    // add your menu here...
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,MenuItem item)
  {
    // handles your action menu clicked event
    returntrue;
  }
}
```